# Open RSS file in chrome then it ask for download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, rss

I am working on `Rails application` where i created `RSS feeds.`

When i open link into `Firefox` it open good but in `chrome` it ask for download file or nothing.

What actually issue here or give me proper way to create and `display RSS link` if any buddy have a experience in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might be because, Your Google chrome does not have built in rss reader, to make google chrome lighter.

More information [here](https://superuser.com/questions/456411/view-rss-feeds-in-chrome-instead-of-downloading-it).

To get rid of this problem you can add rss reader in google chrome by adding it from chrome webstore.

Follow below steps :

1. In your Chrome browser open
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/rss?hl=en-US
2. Enter 'RSS Feed Reader' in the search box (top left)
3. Press your 'Enter' key
4. In the results click the '+ Add to Chrome' button next to 'RSS Feed Reader'